# Explanation of converting from void* to int in c

Tags: c, type-conversion

in my code i have:

```
int number_compare(void *val1, void *val2) {
    if (*(int*) val1 < *(int*s) val2) {
```

So basically to convert from void* to int i have to cast *(int *).

This works and give me the correct results, could someone please tell me why though or point me to a thread that explains it. I have already looked and cannot find an answer I understand.

Comment: That `s` is a typo, right?

Comment: Thanks for clearing your snippets, I learned how to cast the pointer to what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not converting a `void *` to an `int`.  It's interpreting whatever the `void *` is pointing at as an `int`.  Break it down:

```
val1           // void pointer - not dereferenceable
(int *)val1    // pointer to 'int'
*(int *)val1   // the 'int' being pointed to
```

So your function is getting passed two pointers: it then interprets them as pointers to `int` and dereferences them, comparing the two `int` values being pointed to.

In contrast, converting from a `void *` to an `int` would look something like this:

```
int x = (int)val1;
```

But that's almost certainly not what you want - first because `int` is signed, and pointers aren't, and second because `int` and pointer types might not be the same size.

Comment: The function *assumes* that both `void*` pointers point to properly aligned `int` objects. It's likely a comparison function to be used with `qsort` or `bsearch`; since those functions can work on arrays of any types, and C doesn't have templates, they use `void*` as a generic pointer type.

Comment: Well, it either makes the assumption that they're aligned or that the architecture can handle unaligned accesses.

Comment: One could nitpick that if the architecture can handle unaligned accesses, then the `int` objects are "properly aligned" by definition. But yes, good point.

Answer (score 4):

first thing void pointer cannot be defreferenced. maybe because it doesn't yet know how to fetch data. (i.e) if its char should fetch 1 byte, int 4 bytes...

so here first you are converting some address (void pointer) to int pointer.

```
(int*) val1;
```

later to fetch the value from that address [now the system knows it should take data from 4 bytes from that address : val1].

```
*(int*)val1
```

this 'll give you the data in that address.

This is formally said to be casting **"(data_type) data"** casting the data to specified data_type;